# Соответствие русскоязычных и англоязычных терминов в программировании

Tags: книги, терминология

Иногда, читая русские книги, встречаешь непривычные термины, и непонятно - то ли ты сам используешь слишком жаргонный термин, то ли у переводчика мало опыта (прошло много времени и практика изменилась, нет устоявшегося термина и т.п.)

Вопрос очень непраздный, так как приходится всё больше читать материалов на английском (увы, но на русском материалов много меньше) и хочется понимать соответствие терминов.

Пока я выкручиваюсь тем, что:

- взял некоторую книгу (Рихтер) по основам выбранного языка программирования и читал одновременно оригинал и перевод, запоминая базовые термины - и то же самое делаю для новых книг, стараясь чтобы новый материал "пристыковывался" к предыдущему (процент новых терминов был менее 30%)
- отдельно я уважаю книги, в которых есть готовый словарь соответствия терминов (в том же Рихтере он есть)
- смотрю по статьям на хабре каким переводом пользуются (тупо поиском), особая удача -- когда статья переводная

А что делаете вы? Может быть есть какие-то более эффективные способы? Скажем, я бы не отказался посмотреть какой-то глоссарий в сети.

Comment: Возможно, это стоит на мету перенести, туда вроде всякие "разговоры о работе" выносят?

Comment: как бы не закрыли по «primarily opinion-based») А вопрос толковый, думаю, многих постоянно затрагивает таковая проблема

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Надо не закрывать, а законсервировать и прикрепить где-нибудь как пример opinion-based as it is.

Comment: "Вопрос очень непраздный, ..." - а каков собственно вопрос? Из заголовка он явно не следует.