# Обобщения оператор where

Tags: c#, generics

Подскажите как загуглить что бы почитать о операторе/ключевом слове `where` в такой конструкции например:

```
public class DbSet<TEntity> : DbQuery<TEntity>, IDbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable, IInternalSetAdapter where TEntity : class
```

Comment: Документацию, например: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ссылка прекрасная, но вы дали рыбу, а спрашивали где найти удочку. Не знаю, может это тоже стоит на мету перенести? "Как научиться гуглить".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретная [ссылка на документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) вам дана в комментариях, а если вам хочется научиться такому же фокусу (самому готовит запрос в гугл) - то нужно научиться немного английскому языку и понимать переводы терминов.

Т.е. можно гуглить c# generic where constraint или c# generic type constraint. Чем точнее вы знаете область - тем меньше ссылок перерывать. Ну и для этого хорошо понимать предметную область - как сказать на английском "обобщение/дженерик" (да, многие термины калькированы и вы их должны знать) и как сказать "ограничение".

Обратите внимание: приведённая ссылка была чуть ли не первой и в заголовке русского текста вы можете посмотреть английские термины, они как раз такие и были.

Также смотрите смежные вопросы:

- [Соответствие русскоязычных и англоязычных терминов в программировании](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/856750/213987)

Comment: На самом деле достаточно просто "c# where", именно так я и гуглил. Если бы ТС знал что это "generic" и "constraint", то вопроса, может, и не возникло бы. Хотя, что мешало просто загуглить как я...

Comment: Подкол засчитан. Проблема была в том, что я не мог найти, как такая конструкция называется(не обобщения, а обобщение с использованием where - constraint). Спасибо. Жаль, я не родился сразу умным, как родились вы, не задавал бы таких вопросов. Кстати, в Троелсене, я видимо проспал эту главу.

Comment: @АндрейNOP я искал так "обобщение c# where"